Experiencing connectivity issues with certain sites but not others
I recently switched ISPs (based in Australia) and since connecting I have had issues with certain sites. When attempting to load the websites in the browser, I either get "This connection has timed out" or "Unable to connect" I can see no pattern between the sites that work and those that don't. Running a tracert to sites that don't load show that the link fails multiple hops away from my node.
.
I have tested multiple tracerts to websites that work, and don't work, and this difference is common behavior.
I found this post in which the top answer suggests that external firewalls could be the cause of this. I am trying to discover a solution to this issue, and whether there is something in my control that can fix it as the ISP has not been able to identify the issue.
The modem I am using is D-link DSL-G225 which worked with my old ISP. I have tried changing DNS settings (google open dns and cloudflare) and the issue is present with both. ISP has also changed my IP address and still issue persists.
ETA: used Powershell as suggested in comments and got these results to confirm my inability to access the website:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "accounts.google.com" -InformationLevel "Detailed" -p 443
WARNING: TCP connect to (74.125.68.84 : 443) failed
WARNING: TCP connect to (2404:6800:4003:c02::54 : 443) failed
WARNING: Ping to 74.125.68.84 failed with status: TimedOut
WARNING: Ping to 2404:6800:4003:c02::54 failed
ComputerName            : accounts.google.com
RemoteAddress           : 74.125.68.84
RemotePort              : 443
NameResolutionResults   : 74.125.68.84
2404:6800:4003:c02::54
MatchingIPsecRules      :
NetworkIsolationContext : Internet
InterfaceAlias          : Wi-Fi
SourceAddress           : 192.168.1.12
NetRoute (NextHop)      : 192.168.1.1
PingSucceeded           : False
TcpTestSucceeded        : False

what is the exact error you receive in the browser? traceroute timeouts are not an indication of failure on the path I'm afraid. lots of sites and nodes block ICMP traffic which is required for traceroute to work properly. you are better off using TCP layer diagnostics to test service layer accessibility, rather than trying to diagnose the path. there is basically nothing you can do about routing failures anyway, other than to attempt to change the path via VPNs or proxies. try powershell's test-netconnection instead to test your access to the sites services.

Have you ruled out DNS lookup issues? E.G., try a different DNS resolution server, such as Clouflare 1.1.1.1 or Google 8.8.8.8, or switch to Automatic resolution.

@DrMoishePippik Hi, yes I have tried three different DNS server sets as well as automatic, and experience the issue with all.

@FrankThomas Hi, thanks for your reply. I used the powershell command as suggested and it confirms that I am unable to access accounts.google.com. I have updated the post with the results as it was too long and not properly formatted in the comment.

well, it failed to ping, but if you add  -p 443 on the end of it, it will tell you whether the HTTPS service is available, even if it won't respond to ping.

@FrankThomas sorry, my lack of knowledge there caught me out. Updated showing the TCPTest failed.

@JoepvanSteen This actually works as a workaround! While using TunnelBear I can access those sites! Any ideas of what this could lead to as the root cause of the issue?

so at this point you have sufficiently troubleshot the problem to narrow it down to your ISP. there really isn't any other party that could be causing the issue. its also possible that the service has blocklisted your entire ISPs network, though that implies that your ISP is pretty shady and attracting lots of bad subscribers.
